# BTRFS cannot delete snapshot - operation not permited

Tags: delete, btrfs, snapshot

I cannot delete a the btrfs subvolume "2014-07-28" which is a snapshot of the "@" created by the kubuntu installer to serve as the kubuntu root.

```
teneighty@teneighty-MS-7924:/$ sudo mount -o subvolid=5 /dev/sda5 /mnt
teneighty@teneighty-MS-7924:/$ sudo btrfs sub list /mnt
ID 257 gen 1782 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 1574 top level 5 path @home
ID 266 gen 1761 top level 5 path 2014-07-28
teneighty@teneighty-MS-7924:/$ ls /mnt
@  2014-07-28  @home
teneighty@teneighty-MS-7924:/$ sudo btrfs sub del /mnt/2014-07-28/
Delete subvolume '/mnt/2014-07-28'
ERROR: cannot delete '/mnt/2014-07-28' - Operation not permitted
```

tried apt-btrfs-snapshot delete:

```
teneighty@teneighty-MS-7924:/$ sudo apt-btrfs-snapshot delete /mnt/2014-07-28/
Delete subvolume '/mnt/2014-07-28'
ERROR: cannot delete '/mnt/2014-07-28' - Device or resource busy
```

if it's busy, I shouldn't be able to do this, should I?

```
teneighty@teneighty-MS-7924:/$ sudo umount /mnt
```

but it unmounts quietly. Although I tested and it will unmount even if I have /mnt/2014-07-28 open in a file manager.

I created the snapshot after installing kubuntu 14.04, and then performed a substantial system update. After the update I created another snapshot, and I was able to delete that one without a problem. But the one I want to delete is the preupdate snapshot since everything is working fine post-update, I don't expect I will need to roll back to a fresh installion stage.

I have also attempted to delete it using the kubuntu live USB I installed from, that didn't work either. Then I tried apt-btrfs-snapshot delete, and

It is likely that this snapshot was originally located at @/snapshots/2014-07-28, and then I gained a better understanding of the ubuntu BTRFS layout from documentation at help.ubuntu.com, so I moved my snapshots to the root BTRFS volume. I tried to move it back, but it returned the same error.

What could be causing this error on a snapshot? Why would apt-btrfs-snapshot say it is busy? I don't know where to go from here, but as the file system changes, I am going to need that space back.

Comment: Did you use apt-btrfs-snapshot to create the snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

First check which subvol is default by:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol list /mnt/
ID 319 gen 508029 top level 5 path @plasma
ID 326 gen 508633 top level 5 path @
$ sudo btrfs subvol get-default /mnt/
ID 319 gen 508029 top level 5 path @plasma
```

I want to delete `@plasma` subvol. I had same error while I want to delete (Operation not permitted). You need to change default subvol:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol set-default 326 /mnt/
```

Choose new default subvol by ID. After this you will be able to delete subvol:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvol delete -v /mnt/@plasma/
Transaction commit: none (default)
Delete subvolume (no-commit): '/mnt/@plasma'
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether it is READ-ONLY and set to RW

```
 btrfs property set -ts ./MyClone/@home  ro false
```

see also https://linuxreviews.org/Btrfs#the_HOWTO